# Spring 3 - How to throw an exception when additional request parameters are passed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller mapping, where I pass 2 request params instead of 1. But when done like that Spring is not throwing any exception rather it is ignoring the additional request params.

For eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView eGiftActivation(@RequestParam("value") String value)
```

When I hit my app using `/test.do?value=abcd` it is working fine. But when I pass additional params like `/test.do?value=abcd&extra=unwanted` also it's working fine.

In this case I want Spring to restrict the second URL where additional params are passed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: By saying that throw exception, you mean to say that you don't want to manually go through the request.getParameters() and throw exception if you don't find any?

What do you achieve if extra parameters are restricted? you don't want to ignore others than you require? Just curious.

Comment: if there are additional request params, i need to redirect the user to some error page. So how can i identify if additional request params are present or not

Comment: Answered a way you can achieve it. Hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check it manually, like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView eGiftActivation(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
    if (params.size() != 1 || !params.containsKey("value")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Extra parameters are present"); // or do redirect
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible (For Spring to prevent the request to flow to any controller's method). The reason being that:

- Your controller handles request based on the URI path like, `/app/hello/{name}` rather than the request parameters
- Request parameters are there to give extra set of meta-info for the request rather than endpoint specification of request.

But, if you wanted to restrict the URI path as such, you can use regex and you can avoid. I'm afraid it's not feasible and even the requirement for that never arose.

**Programmatical Way:** 
Having said that, you can take `HttpServletRequest` for parameters and loop through the parameters to check for extra ones:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object eGiftActivation(@RequestParam("value") String value, HttpServletRequest request){
 //check the request.getParameterMap() and throw custom exception if you need and handle using Exception handler or throw invalid request
   return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I prefer handling these kind of validations (if required, what ever may be the reason) inside the Filter generically so that the requests will not even reach the Controller methods.**

Please find the required code to handle inside the Filter as below (logic is almost similar to Slava).

```
 @Component
 public class InvalidParamsRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

 @Override
 protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

        if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/test") && (params.size() != 1    || !params.containsKey("value"))) {

            //Here, Send back the Error Response OR Redirect to Error Page

        } else {        
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
     }
 }
```